# Comparison between polynomial norms

Tags: calculus, analysis, polynomials, normed-spaces, equivalent-metrics

For $p=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_k X^k \in \mathbb{C}[X]$, we note $||p||_{\infty}= \max\{|a_k| \: / \: 0 \leq k \leq n \}$ and $||p||_{\mathbb{D}} = \max \{ |p(z)| \: / \: |z| \leq 1 \} = \max \{ |p(z)| \: / \: |z| = 1 \}$.

Considering the sequence $p_n(z) = 1 + z + ... + z^n$, it is easy to see that we cannot find a constant $C >0$ such that $||\cdot||_{\mathbb{D}} \leq C ||\cdot||_{\infty}$, as $||p_n||_{\infty}=1$ and $||p_n||_{\mathbb{D}} \geq |p_n(1)| = n+1 \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{}+ \infty$.

But what about the reverse inequality ? Can we find a constant $C>0$ such that $||\cdot||_{\infty} \leq C ||\cdot||_{\mathbb{D}}$ ?

Comment: `\|` looks a bit nicer for norms than `||`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from [Cauchy's differentiation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) that
$$
 |a_k| \le \max \{ |p(z)| : |z| = 1 \}
$$
for all coefficients, so that in your notation $\|\cdot\|_{\infty} \leq  \|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{D}}$.